# EB Setup with per-environment artifacts

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up a CLI deployment of a tomcat application using Elastic Beanstalk.

The way things are currently set up is that there are builds of the develop, stage and production branches.  Each produces a war, but they're different wars.  They should share a lot of setup (instance type, security group, memory settings), but with some differences between JVM arguments.

Is there a way to have a develop, stage and production EB environments where the respective wars are uploaded and deployed?  Or do I need to back off and have separate eb applications?